# How can I make a single link on a website open multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html

By using a single link, I can make two pages appear, however I haven't been able to get it to work for three. Can anyone help me out and, if so, show your code.

Comment: Um... sorry don't worry. I figured it out

    <a href="http://virtual-doctor.net" onclick="window.open('http://runningrss.com');window.open('http://google.com.com');
return true;">multilink</a>

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use JavaScript for that.

HTML code

```
<a href="#" id="linkId">Click Here</a>
```

JavaScript code

```
$('#linkId').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://google.com');
    window.open('http://facebook.com');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="yourlink">Click Here</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://yoururl1.com');
    window.open('http://yoururl2.com');
});
```

window.open also can take additional parameters. See them here: `http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml`

You should also know that window.open is sometimes blocked by popup blockers and/or ad-filters.